# I want to send the value from modal to the table from the row that we edited

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have set these values when I edit the rows in the table.

```
var indexrows = $(d).closest("tr").index();
var currentrow = $(d).closest("tr");
```

This is the table name: `$('#tblindeximage')`

This is the value in modal:

```
var pd_head_name = $('#index_head_name').val();
var pd_detail_name = $('#index_detail_name').val();
```

And I want to send to the row where we have called modal:

```
$("td:eq(" + indexrows + ")", $(currentrow)).find('.cls-pd_main_head').html(pd_head_name);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NayUp.jpg)

Comment: Pls show your html

Answer (score 0):

your code:

```
$("td:eq(" + indexrows + ")", $(currentrow)).find('.cls-pd_main_head').html(pd_head_name);
```

possible solution:

```
$("td:eq(" + indexrows + ")", $(currentrow)).find('.cls-pd_main_head').text(pd_head_name);
```

**UPDATE:**

if `$('#index_head_name').val();` returns nothing. change it to `.text();`

Comment: just make sure `$('#index_head_name').val()` really returns a value

Comment: what does `$('#index_head_name').val()` returns?

Comment: Yes, it has value

Comment: I find a way to succeed. Thank you.                                     
$(currentrow).find('.cls-pd_main_head').html(pd_head_name);